# How do I get an average of one column based on the value of another column?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

***SQL Question***

I am currently trying to get the average of a certain subset of a column based on the shared value of another column.  Here's some example data:

```
Score     Player
  5          1
  9          1
  7          1
  8          2
  3          2
  6          2
```

So how can I get the average of Player 1's scores separately from Player 2's?  My first thought is to try something like:

```
SELECT AVG(score) FROM table WHERE DISTINCT player
```

But, of course, `distinct` only works in the `select` portion of the query. Any attempt I've made to use a subquery results in an error saying:

> the subquery returns more than one row.

Any assistance anyone could give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what did you mean by **how can I get the average of Player 1's scores separately from Player 2's?**? Please add your expected output for the above dataset. Btw, `...WHERE Player=1` would do.

Comment: are you using sql-server or mysql? or you can tag the question with just sql if you want ansi sql compliant answer

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're looking for `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Player, AVG(Score)
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY Player;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this below query. I hope you are looking for this solution.

[LIVE DEMO](http://rextester.com/XZN73263)

```
SELECT
    Player,
    AVG(Score) AS Avarage
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    Player
```

**Output:**

[image]